# JQuery script for form submit is working fine in Chrome but not in IE11

Tags: jquery

The following is my simple code for a form submit handler through jQuery script. It runs well with Chrome but not in IE11. There is no action in case of IE11 whereas in Chrome, the alert message is shown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></meta>
  <title>Validate login from database table using jQuery JSP & jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Submit prevented");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="">
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="one"><br> 
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="two"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I placed your logic in an executable snippet and ran it in IE11 where it worked fine; the `alert()` appeared as expected. Please check the console for errors in your local version. Also check you're definitely using IE11 as the jQuery 3 branch removed a lot of support for older IE browsers, so that may be part of the issue.

Comment: Also note that `<meta />` tags are self closing, and HTML4 is a rather odd choice, considering how outdated it is now.

Comment: I tested your code on IE11 and works properly.

Comment: No issues here on IE11